# How return transaction hash from wallet to android app after payment?

Tags: wallet, java, android, mycelium-wallet

Scenario: I have my android app where customers can pay by bitcoins. 
For this I created intent with uri like:

> bitcoin:[address]?amount=..

and using startActivityForResult  it opens wallet with pre-filled destination address and amount. After payment was sent, wallet back to my app transaction_hash and I can "catch" it in response(onActivityResult).

I tried few wallets and it works only in Mycelium. 
I want to implement the same for other currencies, like BCH and LTC and wonder if any other wallets support it in the way above or there are other better approaches exist.

Update: it called InAppPayments https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/wiki/InAppPayments.

So, I am looking for wallets which support InAppPayments for btc, bch and ltc.